# зависимая синхронизация методов

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Имеется 1 объект и 2 метода.

```
public File putData(String key, String content) {
}

public void sendData() {
}
```

Первый метод могут выполнять произвольное количество потоков одновременно. При выполнении второго метода (любым из потоков) - необходимо заблокировать доступ (забрать монитор у объекта, НО дождавшись завершения всех вызовов первого метода), выполнить метод и продолжить выполнять "накопившийся" стек вызовов 1 метода.

У меня получилось примерно так. Есть более оптимизированное и менее громоздкое решение?))

```
volatile boolean lock = false;
volatile int count = 0;

public File putData(String key, String content) {
   if (!lock) {
      count++;
      // code
      count--;
   } else {
      synchronized (this) {
         // code
      }
   }
} 

public synchronized void sendData() {
   lock = true;
   while(count!=0) Thread.yield();
   // code
   lock = false;
}
```

Comment: Зачем такое городить? Почему просто synchronized не сделать? Вы учитываете в своей идее случай, когда два разных потока одновременно кладут разные значения одного ключа? Что будет в таком случае?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Похоже, что вы можете использовать `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. Его использование разрешает наличие нескольких читателей и только одного писателя. При этом:

- лок на чтение можно взять только если в данный момент никто не
  пишет и никто не запросил доступ на запись
- лок на запись можно взять только если в данный момент никто не читает
  и не пишет

Т.о. в первом методе вам нужно брать лок на чтение, во втором -- лок на запись. Лок на запись дождется завершения всех текущих чтений, при этом все новые попытки чтения будут вставать в очередь.

```
final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public File putData(String key, String content) {
   lock.readLock().lock();
   try {
      // code
   }
   finally
   {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
   }
} 

public void sendData() {
   lock.writeLock().lock();
   try {
      // code
   }
   finally
   {
      lock.writeLock().unlock();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во первых инкремент на volatile счетчике это не атомарная операция, так что это даже работать не будет - нужно менять на AtomicInteger.

Во вторых потоки которые ждали в первом методе пока кончится запись, по окончанию записи все равно висят на одном локе.

---

Необходимость всего этого велосипеда под сомнением. Если нужно складывать значения в мапу а потом время от времени отсылать ее куда то - я бы сделал deepCopy, того что отсылается внутри send метода, а synchronized заменил на read/write локи. И это при условии, что частота записей высокая, а отсылка занимает много времени. Если таких ограничений нет, обычного synchronized на обоих методах вполне хватит.